# vim struggles when copy-pasting large blocks of text in from an external window

Tags: vim

I select and copy a large block of plain text from some file (e.g. gedit).  I run `:set paste` and then enter insert mode, and paste the text in using the right mouse-button menu.  vim them uses 100% cpu for the next several minutes before successfully pasting my text in.  The text is usually only a few pages, and takes less than a second to paste into other applications (gedit window, web window, etc).  What is vim doing with all those clock cycles and how can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably file a bug report against vim on this one.

Comment: okay, thanks.  I've posted my bug to bugs@vim.org as suggested here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html, we'll see if anything happens.

Answer (score 6):

Based on a suggestion from the maintainer after filing a bug report, it seems this problem is caused by the syntax highlighter.  Disabling syntax highlighting temporarily (`:set syntax=off`) fixes this, though having to do both that and `:set paste`, and then toggle each back again is rather annoying (yes, I know I could map the commands in `.vimrc`.  It is still annoying).   Pasting also runs faster in gvim than in vim.  Not sure why.

So, current answer is "turn off syntax highlighting"...

Comment: Why don't you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Because I feel that Jim's answer is correct, this is a bug.  There's no reason one should need to turn syntax highlighting off for a simple copy-paste to work smoothly like it does in gedit, etc.  Just seems that the bug depends on the syntax highlighter extension, not base vim.

Comment: Who is then that cboettig that wrote: So, current answer is "turn off syntax highlighting"... :-). I'm being sarcastic of course but don't get me wrong, I'm just noting the contradiction. Anyway after investigating a bit more I thing that the evilsoup's answer is even more to the point. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258561/pasting-a-huge-amount-of-text-into-vim-is-slow

Comment: This may also be caused by `foldexpr`. When I'm pasting into markdown, just disabling syntax doesn't help. I've documented a fix in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61694190/3407728

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to paste text in vim is with the `p` command (from normal mode).

To paste from the xclipboard (the 'middle-click' clipboard), you should use `"*p`. To paste from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> clipbaord, use `"+p`.

Comment: ...Unless your vim doesn't support `”+`, like the Mac default version. (: